# Passing prop functions with "this" through a custom component to child component

Tags: react-native

I'm attempting to create a custom TextInput - I don't want to extend the TextInput class directly because I might be working with other libraries in the future. But I do want to pass the `onChangeText` function from the top-level of my script down through my custom component into the child TextInput

In the following script I've provided a default `onChangeText` function for my custom component that I would like to pass down to the TextInput. Obviously in this case, the "this" setState is not referring to the TextInput like I want it to. It's referring to my custom component.

And even if I could figure out how to get the default `onChangeText` to refer to the TextInput object's setState, how would I be able to refer to it when I actually use MyTextInput `onChangeText`=(text)=>???? at all ?

```
export class MyTextInput extends React.Component {
    static propTypes = {
        placeholder: PropTypes.string,
        style: PropTypes.object,
        onChangeText: PropTypes.func,
        password: PropTypes.bool,
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        password: false,
        onChangeText: (text) => this.setState({text}),
    }



    render() {

        return (
            <TextInput
                style={[styles.textinput, this.props.styles]}
                placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                placeholderTextColor={colors.text}
                secureTextEntry={this.props.password}
                onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText}
              />
        );
    }
}
```

You see obviously the onChangeText in defaultProps has a "this" in it, referring to my component when that function to refer to the TextInput

What do you guys think is the best way to go about this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution

You want to extend `onChangeText` to use parent components without change original acting.
Thus, link method for the `onChangeText` property as below.

```js
export class MyTextInput extends React.Component {
    state = {
      value: '',
    }
    
    static propTypes = {
        placeholder: PropTypes.string,
        style: PropTypes.object,
        onChangeText: PropTypes.func,
        password: PropTypes.bool,
    }

    static defaultProps = {
        password: false,
    }
    
    onChangeText = (value) => {
      this.setState({ value });
      this.props.onChangeText?.(); // Same as this.props.onChangeText && this.props.onChangeText()
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TextInput
                style={[styles.textinput, this.props.styles]}
                placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                placeholderTextColor={colors.text}
                secureTextEntry={this.props.password}
                value={this.state.value}
                onChangeText={this.onChangeText}
              />
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your input!! I'm a little confused at the line with this.props.onChangeText?.(); .... is that a typo? Or an indication for something I might be missing?

Comment: I think the problem might be something I added in that you're not aware of. I'll try to work this through and get back if I can't figure it out - thanks!

Comment: @Pete It is not typo. It is called the optional chaning that is using to check null. I commented same line.

Comment: In other expression, you can use  `if (this.props.onCgangeText != null) this.props.onChangeText()` as same way.

Comment: And the code which  is in my answer is not tested. So tell me if you get some error about code.